# Use values saved from form to render page

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views

I feel like this is pretty straightforward but I am clearly doing something wrong.

I'm trying to build an auctioning site. After the user has completed the online form to create a new listing, once the form is submitted I want the page to redirect to that new listing page. Right now, it is redirecting to the listing page but the page is not rendering with the values input in the form. However if I go back to the homepage, click on that new listing created then it takes me to the listing page just fine and loads up with all the information input in the form. Please could someone take a look and shed some light. I suspect the problem lies in my views.py.

**models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.99)])
    image = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings")
    lister = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self): 
        return f"Product: {self.title} \nDescription: {self.description} \nCurrent Price: £{self.price}\nImage: {self.image} \nCategory: {self.category} \nListed by: {self.lister}"
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = ["title", "description", "price", "image", "category"]

    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
    price = forms.DecimalField(label='Starting Bid Price (£)')
    image = forms.URLField(widget=forms.URLInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
```

**views.py**

```
def newListing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewListingForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            newlisting = form.save(commit=False)
            newlisting.lister = request.user
            listing = newlisting.save()
            return render(request, "auctions/listingPage.html", {
                "listing": listing
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
                "form": form,
            })  
    else:
        form = NewListingForm()
    return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
        "form": form
    })
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("listing/<int:listing_id>", views.listing, name="listing"),
    path("NewListing", views.newListing, name="newListing")
]
```

Comment: as first view looks every thing fine. Its depend on how you where rendering your instance object to the template. Also have a look on  newlisting.save() method returning the created instance object or not. It might return None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to delete because I found the answer now but I will answer my own question in case this helps someone else.

A kind person on reddit explained that instead of render I should use redirect and pass in newlisting.id as the listing_id to satisfy the argument in my url.

My views.py now looks like this:

```
def newListing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewListingForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            newlisting = form.save(commit=False)
            newlisting.lister = request.user
            listing = newlisting.save()
            return redirect("listing", listing_id=newlisting.id)
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
                "form": form,
            })  
    else:
        form = NewListingForm()
    return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
        "form": form
    })
```